# Bower error : bower ESUDO Cannot be run with sudo?

Tags: permissions, sudo, 17.04

I'm on Ubuntu 17.04. Not sure if I have bower installed or not:

```
$ sudo npm install -g bower

/usr/bin/bower -> /usr/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
/usr/lib
└── bower@1.8.0
```

When I try to check and I get errors:

```
$ bower -V
bower ESUDO         Cannot be run with sudo

Additional error details:                                                                                                                                                         
Since bower is a user command, there is no need to execute it with superuser permissions.
If you're having permission errors when using bower without sudo, please spend a few minutes learning more about how your system should work and make any necessary repairs.

http://www.joyent.com/blog/installing-node-and-npm
https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814

You can however run a command with sudo using --allow-root option

Stack trace:
Error: Cannot be run with sudo
    at createError (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/util/createError.js:4:15)
    at rootCheck (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/util/rootCheck.js:26:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/bin/bower.js:33:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)

Console trace:
Error
    at StandardRenderer.error (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:81:37)
    at rootCheck (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/util/rootCheck.js:26:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/bin/bower.js:33:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
System info:
Bower version: 1.8.0
Node version: 7.10.0
OS: Linux 4.9.15-x86_64-linode81 x64
```

When I try to install packages with my program I get errors too:

```
[localhost] local: bower install
bower ESUDO         Cannot be run with sudo

Additional error details:                                                                                                                                                         
Since bower is a user command, there is no need to execute it with superuser permissions.
If you're having permission errors when using bower without sudo, please spend a few minutes learning more about how your system should work and make any necessary repairs.

http://www.joyent.com/blog/installing-node-and-npm
https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814

You can however run a command with sudo using --allow-root option

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'bower install'

Aborting.
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: You seem to be running `bower` as root or with `sudo`, which you should not do. It is meant to run only with restricted user privileges and contains a safety check to abort if it runs with root rights.

Comment: @ByteCommander yes I log in the server as a root because this is a production server and I only have this account. so what should i do then?

Comment: As the error message suggested, there is a `--allow-root` switch to override the safety check. Note that `bower` will download and execute untrusted code though, which should definitely not be done as root for various reasons, especially not on a production server.

Comment: @ByteCommander yes it fixed with `--allow-root`.  so ideally i should create a new user account?

Comment: That would be a good idea for security reasons, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be running `bower` as root or with `sudo`, which you should not do. It is meant to run only with restricted user privileges and contains a safety check to abort if it runs with root rights.

This is implemented for security reasons, because `bower` will download and execute untrusted code to do its job. That should definitely not be done as root for various reasons, especially not on a production server.

As the error message suggested, there is a `--allow-root` switch to override the safety check and run it even though you are root.

However, the optimal and secure way to go would be to create a separate user account with limited privileges and use that one instead of doing everything as root, which does not only include `bower`.